# Bootstrap 3 Responsive Columns for Ecommerce Website

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm designing an ecommerce site using Bootstrap 3. For the products, I have the products in rows, designed like boxes. I'm using Bootstrap's new grid system to try and make it not look scrunched when it get's smaller. On a large screen, it's set up with 3 columns on each row, using .col-lg-4. Then I add the .col-md-6 to switch to two items on a medium sized device.

However, since the original rows start with 3 columns, I'm one off when it hits the medium class. The images should show what I'm trying to say:

I start with this:

http://siteburbia.com/images/bootstrap-col-4.png

Then get this when it switches to medium:

http://siteburbia.com/images/bootstrap-col-6.png

Is it possible to fix this in Bootstrap 3, or will I have to do something with PHP (which the site will be built with to display the products dynamically). By fix, I mean fill in that odd space with a .col-md-6.

Thanks!

Comment: put everything in a single row. once the row fills up it automatically goes to next row anyways.

Comment: @user2930100 I've tried that. The columns don't work correctly that way.

Comment: Look at the bootstrap example(view source for the 6 boxes in the bottom): http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: Awesome! It was a clearfix problem, but without that example I wouldn't have figured it out. Thanks!